# Prove that if $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is orthogonal to every $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\vec{a} = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I was requested to prove that, given $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal to every $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\vec{a} = 0$. I am aware this is a simple problem, but I'm new to linear algebra (started learning today) and was wondering whether my proof is correct. Here's my attempt.

$I.$ Assume $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x} = 0 \space \space \forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

$II.$ Either $\vec{a} = 0$ or $\vec{a} \neq 0$. If $\vec{a} \neq 0$, there is a non-empty set $\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \vec{a} \cdot \vec{x} \neq 0\}$. This is trivial, since (for example) $\vec{a} \neq 0 \implies \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} \neq 0$, with $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. But this contradicts assumption $I$.

$III.$ It follows, via *reductio ad absurdum*, that assumption $I$ implies $\vec{a} = 0$.

I know this is very simple, but I could use some validation given my experience in the branch of linear algebra is two hours long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea in II, but you can remove the unnecessary proof by contradiction. Suppose $\vec a\in\Bbb R^3$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\Bbb R^3$. Then, in particular, it is orthogonal to itself, so $0=\vec a\cdot\vec a = \|\vec a\|^2$. Thus, $\vec a = \vec 0$.

Comment: Much simpler. Thank you!